# TODAY FUNCTION IN EMEDITOR

Tags: emeditor

Please how do i get "today's date function" into a Column on Emeditor? Similar to Excel

Comment: Are you looking for a macro? How similar is it to Excel? Please clarify your question.

Comment: It's quite simple...What java script can I use to get today's date in a column in emeditor? If you have a macro that would be great

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a JavaScript macro like this:

```
var today = new Date();
var dd = today.getDate();
var mm = today.getMonth() + 1;
var yyyy = today.getFullYear();
document.write( mm + '/' + dd + '/' + yyyy );
```

Comment: You're welcome. Please click the checkmark on the left to show that you accept the answer. Please do so for all your questions.